# Executing navigation commands within a function

Tags: vim

I'd like to execute a function and that the function itself handles movement. For example, I'd like it to do a substitution and then move to a line below:

```
function SubThis()
  s/a/b/g
  execute "j"
endfunction
```

Of course, what I've tried doesn't work. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As romainl said, it's better to just type `normal j`.

Comment: Even simpler: `normal j`.